# Pinescript - high or low does not quite reach the Fibonacci line

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I would like to evaluate when the candlestick hits high or low on a Fibonacci line. this works in many cases. Unfortunately not in all cases. So the question is: How can I dynamically query the not quite reaching the Fibonacciline anyway. I tried using a factor for the average unachieved value difference. Unfortunately I have the case again that sometimes the query fits and sometimes other non-evaluable highs and lows are queried. It would therefore be interesting to query the value difference somehow dynamically. Is that possible? And if so how? I'm not good enough in Pinescript for such a calculation

[image: Screen]